# get shortcode value

Tags: plugins, php, shortcode

I created a text field in a shortcode for highcharts where we can choose a footer label for the chart. This is the field:

```
            array(
            'label' => esc_html( 'Footer label' ),
            'description' => esc_html( 'Choose the footer label' ),
            'attr' => 'footer_caption',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
```

Until here its all good, the field is created and its saving the value i put in there and its in the database too. Example of the rendered html and what shows up in the database:

```
<input type="text" class="regular-text" name="footer_caption" id="shortcode-ui-footer_caption-c42" value="test caption" placeholder="">
```

and:

```
[the_chart chart="23" footer_caption="test caption"/]
```

The problem is that i cant get the value of the field. In this chart for eg: `test caption`

Im not very used to PHP but i tried in a bunch of different ways to retrieve the value on `footer_caption` but with no luck. Im gonna have to pass that value in another function, so can someone help me out and tell me how i can retrieve the value of `footer_caption`?

Answer (score 2):

```
    add_shortcode('the_chart ', 'high_chart');
        function high_chart($atts, $content = null) {
           //extract the cart and footer_caption value 
            extract(shortcode_atts(array( 'chart' => null, 'footer_caption' => null), $atts));
            /*
               * process your chart and footer_caption value as
               * $chart and $footer_caption and return the process data
             */
            $return_html = 'chart id:'. $chart.'<br/> Footer Caption:'. 
            $footer_caption;
            return $return_html

        }
```

For reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode
Hope that you understand!

Comment: Your code works great, but I'm surprised WordPress uses such ugly syntax.